# How can i make ipythons RichIPythonWidget use pyside in a pyinstaller environment?

Tags: python, ipython, pyside, pyinstaller

I have an application that i build using pyinstaller, and it uses PySide for its Qt Gui. I included an interactive prompt by embedding an ipython qtconsole.
This breaks the builds created by pyinstaller.

Here is a minimal (non-)working example:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *

from IPython.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget import RichIPythonWidget
from IPython.qt.inprocess import QtInProcessKernelManager
from IPython.lib import guisupport

class IPythonWidget(RichIPythonWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.app = app = guisupport.get_app_qt4()
        self.kernel_manager = kernel_manager = QtInProcessKernelManager()
        kernel_manager.start_kernel()

        self.kernel = kernel = kernel_manager.kernel
        kernel.gui = 'qt4'
        self.kernel_client = kernel_client = kernel_manager.client()
        kernel_client.start_channels()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    i = IPythonWidget()
    i.show()
    app.exec_()
```

When run directly from source (python mwe.py), it pops up an ipython qt console window.
When i bundle this with pyinstaller in one directory and run the exe, i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "H:\Home\pydd2swid\build\mwe\out00-PYZ.pyz\IPython.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "H:\Home\pydd2swid\build\mwe\out00-PYZ.pyz\IPython.external.qt", line 23, in <module>
  File "H:\Home\pydd2swid\build\mwe\out00-PYZ.pyz\IPython.external.qt_loaders", line 296, in load_qt
ImportError:
    Could not load requested Qt binding. Please ensure that
    PyQt4 >= 4.7, PyQt5 or PySide >= 1.0.3 is available,
    and only one is imported per session.

    Currently-imported Qt library:   'pyqtv1'
    PyQt4 installed:                 False
    PyQt5 installed:                 False
    PySide >= 1.0.3 installed:       False
    Tried to load:                   ['pyside', 'pyqt', 'pyqt5']
```

and when i build a single executable (pyinstaller -F mwe.py) and run it, i get this:

```
WARNING: file already exists but should not: C:\Users\SARNOW4\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI62362\Include\pyconfig.h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "H:\Home\pydd2swid\build\mwe\out00-PYZ.pyz\PySide", line 41, in <module>
  File "H:\Home\pydd2swid\build\mwe\out00-PYZ.pyz\PySide", line 11, in _setupQtDirectories
  File "H:\Home\pydd2swid\build\mwe\out00-PYZ.pyz\PySide._utils", line 93, in get_pyside_dir
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
RuntimeError: the sip module has already registered a module called PyQt4.QtCore
```

It seems that the way pyinstaller hooks the import mechanism does not work with ipythons qt_loaders. How can i fix this?
I am using pyinstaller 2.1, ipython 3.0, python 2.7 (32-bit) on Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

You can fix it in two ways:

1) Overwrite the function **load_qt** included in *IPython.external.qt_loaders*, e.g.:

```
def load_qt(api_options):
    from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg
    return QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, 'pyside'
```

so, you will force to choose the PySide Module.

2) Another solution without overwriting the IPython Module installed, would be passing the function as reference before importing the IPython widget, e.g.

```
def new_load_qt(api_options):
    from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg
    return QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, 'pyside'

from IPython.external import  qt_loaders
qt_loaders.load_qt = new_load_qt

from IPython.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget import RichIPythonWidget
```

Now it should work.

It was tested using the *PyInstaller Develop Version*